# ld.exe permission denied Makefile gcc

Tags: c, windows, gcc, makefile, linker

I want to compile and link my Project. I have Problems with linking of the target. It is the first time I`m using a makefile.

I think there may be a Problem with the $OBJ or call of the gcc.

I got the following error message:

```
C:\Projekte\playground\Modultest>make all
gcc -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage ./CUnit/headers ./CUnit/sources ./stub ./source ./test   --coverage -o  CUnit-Target
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./CUnit/headers: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./CUnit/sources: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./stub: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./source: Permission denied
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./test: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:54: recipe for target 'CUnit-Target' failed
make: *** [CUnit-Target] Error 1
```

I have no spaces in the path.

This is my makefile

```
# makefile to generate UNIT-tests

# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc

# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
# TODO 

HEADERS =   ./CUnit/headers \
            ./CUnit/sources \
            ./stub \
            ./source \
            ./test
SOURCES =   ./CUnit/sources \
            ./stub \
            ./source \
            ./test

#TODO Linkerflags
LFLAGS = --coverage -o 

# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
LIBS = 

#  TODO define the C source files
TST_SRCS = min.c max.c

SRCS = CUnit.c Automated.c Basic.c Console.c CUCurses.c CUError.c  Cunit_intl.c \
        MyMem.c TestDB.c TestRun.c Util.c wxWidget.c \
        $(TST_SRCS)


# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'

#OBJ = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
#OBJ = $(TST_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
OBJ=$(join($(dir $(SOURCES))), $(notdir $(SRCS:%.c=%.o))) 

# define the executable file 
TARGET = CUnit-Target

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS) $(TARGET)

    @echo build finished            

#execute tests
#Cunit.exe 
# create coverage files
# TODO SRCS max.c min.c ?
#       gcov -b -c -f max min

clean:
        $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

Comment: I can tell you that there's a space missing after `join` in the assignment to `OBJ` (which is why `OBJ` ends up empty), and that the oddly named `HEADERS` variable that contains a list of directories for some reason has no place in the compiler call, and that `$(dir $(SOURCES))` probably doesn't do what you expect (`$(dir ./CUnit/headers)` is `./CUnit`), but quite frankly, it is not obvious from this Makefile how your project is organized, so I am unsure whether fixing these issues will enable you to compile it.

Comment: You are right. 
changed line to OBJ=$(join ($(SOURCES)), $(notdir $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)))  and added -i $(HEADERS) to the call of the Compiler. still have the Problem that the Compiler doesn`t find the sources. Something with the paths is wrong. 

C:\Projekte\playground\Modultest>make all
make: *** No rule to make target '(./CUnit/sourcesCUnit.o', needed by 'CUnit-Target'.  Stop.

Comment: What do you expect the `join` function to do?

Comment: I want to give the gcc the paths. to the files.